# If django has proven that auto-admin can be done well, why hasn't anyone done it in PHP?

Tags: php, django

Just curious, if django has already proven that auto-admin can be done well, why hasn't anyone done it in PHP?

Or if I am wrong and there are good ones out there, what are they?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but maybe CakePHP has what you're looking for?

Comment: Might want to clarify "auto-admin".

Comment: auto-admin ~= automatically building an admin backend to your db

Comment: Well that answers the question then. Autogenerated database admin backends are not uncommon in php frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this, https://github.com/josegonzalez/cake_admin

for CakePHP but still php ;)